# Is there a way to export an asset as a pdf file in AEM 6.4?

Tags: java, pdf, workflow, aem, assets

Wondering if this functionality is possible in AEM. Can you export any asset file `picture1.jpg` or `picture2.png` as a pdf?

I thought this might be possible by creating an additional rendition with `mimetype=application/pdf` in the **DAM Update Asset Workflow**. This did not seem to produce the expected rendition.

Looking for anyone who might have accomplished this before or know how to configure this within AEM. Thanks, any help is welcome!

Comment: I suppose this could be done with a custom step. However, I'm curious as to why one would want to do that instead of just opening and printing the image. Don't all modern browsers across all common operating systems these days support printing web-content to PDF natively?

Comment: You can do it during the workflow that runs after the upload or you could do it when the the PNG asset is requested as PDF (e.g. `/content/dam/mypngimage.pdf`). But both options have drawbacks. Creating it during upload creates a "static" rendition that increases storage requirements for the asset. Doing it on request probably requires you to go a little bit deeper in Sling (maybe build a `ResourceProvider` for this). Anyway: I do not really get the requirement, but if you have to do it I probably go for "on request" to avoid more static renditions.

Comment: Thats a great callout @toniedzwiedz, that would be an easy enough solution.

Comment: Thanks, @Jens, agreed! Just sourcing to see if there was an OOTB way to do it without custom code.